# How do I create a function that takes a users input as a command for file navigation?

Tags: python, function, input, directory, callback

I'm new to Python (programming in general) and am trying to make a very basic file navigation that works like CMD to navigate my 3D files.  So far, it works at a very VERY basic level.  It prints out the subdirectories in the root folder.  From there the user can input the subdirectory to see a list of continued subdirectories. Below is a small example of what I'm trying to do.  This prints the folders in the root, and continues to the subdirectories.  My 'testFunction' is a place holder.  I'm hoping that if the user doesn't see the subdirectory they can type "Back" and go up a level in the folder tree.  Right now it seems to be erroring out because "Back" isn't a sub directory.  I'm not sure how to get around this.  Any suggestions?

```
import os

rootDir = "C:\\Users\\xyz\\OneDrive - xyz"


def testFunction():
    if input("Back"):
        print("Working!")


for file in os.listdir(rootDir):
    d = os.path.join(rootDir, file)
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        subDirTest = d
        print(d)

input_1 = input("Enter Sub Directory ")

userSubDirInput_1 = rootDir + "\\" + input_1 
print(rootDir + userSubDirInput_1) 
subDirectory_1 = userSubDirInput_1 = rootDir + "\\" + input_1
```

I'm hoping as I keep learning I'll have several input functions that control navigation.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I tried to fix your code block. Please check it to make sure the changes I made are correct. In particular, is the last line supposed to be `subDirectory_1 = userSubDirInput_1 = rootDir + "\\" + input_1`? There are 2 `=` there. This is valid Python, but it may not be what you were intending.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a variable that tracks the current directory, and update it in a loop.  If the user enters `Back`, go back; otherwise go into the directory they entered.  Here's a quick example adapted from your current code:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
while True:
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        d = os.path.join(cwd, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            print(d)

    i = input("Enter Sub Directory ")
    if i == "Quit":
        break
    elif i == "Back":
        cwd = os.path.join(*os.path.split(cwd)[:-1])
    else:
        cwd = os.path.join(cwd, i)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, I just need to get it working with what I have so far.  I appreciate the help!